# react native version 0.59.6 apple button login not visible react

Tags: react-native, authentication

using https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication

import React from 'react';

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { AppleButton } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';

async function onAppleButtonPress() {

}

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <AppleButton
        buttonStyle={AppleButton.Style.WHITE}
        buttonType={AppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN}
        style={{
          width: 160, // You must specify a width
          height: 45, // You must specify a height
        }}
        onPress={() => onAppleButtonPress()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need this answer anymore, but currently this error still happens and the solution I found was:

```
import {appleAuth} from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';
```

```
<View>
  {appleAuth.isSupported && (
    <Button title="Sign in with Apple" onPress={AppleSignIn} />
  )}
</View>
```

The `AppleButton` seems to work fine in production:

```
<AppleButton
     buttonStyle={AppleButton.Style.BLACK}
     buttonType={AppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN}
     style={styles.appleButton}
     onPress={AppleSignIn}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

It says in the library [docs](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication#prerequisites-to-using-this-library) that it is only available in React Native v0.60+.

[image]